# Make top-right aligned image clickable

Tags: html, css

I have an image (can vary in size arbitrarely) that I pinned on the top right corner (which was quite a struggle). The image should maximally become 108px high and 17% wide (with respect to the outer div).
This works (How? -> just take the example code and change `a` to `div` and remove `href=""`).

Now I would like to make the image clickable (link to another website).
Unfortunately, with everything I try I either mess the image positioning/sizing up or the clickable area does not have the same position and size as the image itself.

In the following example, depending on the window size, the area is too wide or to high.
I colored the clickable area red. This area should be as big as the image. But, of course, in this case the `a` element is also the container for the image which defines the image size.
Thus, it has to be solved differently. But if the clickable area is colored red in the potential solution, no red should be visible, because this would mean that the clickable area exceeds the image (of course, a area to small would also not be desireable).

```css
#logo-image{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: 100% 0%;
}
#logo-image-container{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height: 108px;
    width: 17%;
background: red;
}

#outer-logo-image-container{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-logo-image-container">
  
    <!-- change div to a and add href as attempt to make image clickable -->
    <a id="logo-image-container" href="stackoverflow.com">
        <img id="logo-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiVY5.png">
    </a>

</div>
```

A valid solution would also be a solution that includes replacing the mechanism for top-right alignment.

Browser: Chromium Edge

Environment: Angular 7

Comment: What do you mean by `image positioning/sizing up or the clickable area does not fit exactly on the image`?

Comment: The area, which is clickable, is bigger than the image itself.

Comment: @JFFIGK you have taken a square image and trying to in a rectangular area as you set the width and hence it is clickable beyond the image. You need to define the actual image size and shape first and then use it accordingly.

Comment: The image is square accidentally, but the problem also exists with rectangular images. My actual image size is and should be dependant on the dynamic rectangular area (or its size).

Comment: I tried also to add another nested div inbetween the rectangle and the image, but I could not keep the image size working that way

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the code by adding in a fiddle, you have added an height of 108px for `#logo-image-container` this makes the container grow in height even the image is finished. Please remove the height property. That will work for you I think.

```
#logo-image-container{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    /* height: 108px; */
    width: 17%;
}
```

```css
#logo-image{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: 100% 0%;
}

#logo-image-container{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    /* height: 108px; */
    width: 17%;
}

#outer-logo-image-container{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-logo-image-container">
  <a id="logo-image-container" href="http://stackoverflow.com">
    <img id="logo-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiVY5.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: OP's requirement is to keep the height static and not more than mentioned. The problem is OP is trying to fit in a square image in a rectangular click area!

Comment: @JFFIGK fro square fit you have either to set width and height in px or in % both cant be done at the same time.

Comment: Nothing which I would not want to do: I would like to insert another div (or rather 'a' because it should be clickable) between the rectangle(logo-image-container) and the image (logo-image), which has 100% of the height of the image and 100% of the width of the image.This way only the image would be clickable. I just don't know how to achieve that without destroying the current layout properties.

Comment: A way to achieve this could be to use object fit on that additionally inserted div/a; bit there I have the problem that the additionally inserted div/a has not the size of the image. so I somehow have to set the size of the intermediary div to the size of the image and then object fit it into the rectangular container.